# What driver name do I use to connect Go sqlx to Postgres using the pgx driver?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx, pgx

Or alternatively, what additional imports do I need?

I'd like to start using Postgres as my main DBMS for some development I am doing, and my research suggests that `pgx` is the database driver of choice at this time.  I have setup a connection package:

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func PgConnect(username, password, host, app string) *sqlx.DB {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s?app+name=%s&sslmode=allow", url.QueryEscape(username), url.QueryEscape(password), host, app)
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to connect to sqlserver://%s:%s@%s err: %s", username, "xxxxxxxxxxxx", host, err)
    }

    return db
}
```

The URL evaluates to:

```
postgres://user:password@database-host:5432/database-name?app+name=app-name&sslmode=allow
```

and I've also tried the prefix of `postgresql` here because I've seen both in places on the internet.

For the driver name in the `sqlx.Connect("postgres", s)` call I have tried `postgres`, `postgresql` and `pgx`.

In all cases the call to connect fails with the error:

```
sql: unknown driver "postgres" (forgotten import?)
```

The same code (with driver `mssql` and mssql URL) works connection to Microsoft SQL Server.

Can anyone help me get this going?  I've found very little on the internet for this combination of language/driver/sqlx/postgres.

Comment: Should be `pgx`, if that don't work try importing the `stdlib` subpackage (in place of `jackc/pgx/v5`). See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.0.4/stdlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.0.4/stdlib), we can see that the driver's name is `pgx`:

> A database/sql connection can be established through sql.Open.
>
> ```
> db, err := sql.Open("pgx", "postgres://pgx_md5:secret@localhost:5432/pgx_test?sslmode=disable")
> if err != nil {
>   return err
> }
> ```

So you'll need to do two things:

1. Use the proper driver name:

   ```golang
       db, err := sqlx.Connect("pgx", s)
   ```
2. Import the stdlib compatibility pacakge:

   ```golang
   import (
       _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib" // Standard library bindings for pgx
   )
   ```